# How to enumerate the number of solutions in sylvester equations and how to solve

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, maple, sylvester-equation

how to solve a, b, c and d for below equations:

Both known Matrix and solution Matrix Properties

```
Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]);
a*b = 1
c*d = 1

conjugate(a*c)-b*d = 0
Determinant(Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]])) = sqrt(3)*I
a*d-b*c = sqrt(3)*I
```

How to solve system AA when known Jesus7 to find Jesus2 which is Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]) ?

```
Sylvestersolve(Jesus7,Jesus7,matrix([[0,0],[0,0]]))
```

It return 0 matrix but actually has solution
How many solutions can it have?
Is sylvester equation isomorphism? How to test?

```
Jesus7 := Matrix(2, 2, {(1, 1) = (1296309/5)*(22243/5+((7358/5)*I)*sqrt(3))/((-384813/10+((33701837/10)*I)*sqrt(3))*(-2277/10+((13/10)*I)*sqrt(3))), (1, 2) = (1296309/5)*(22243/5-((7358/5)*I)*sqrt(3))/((-384813/10-((33701837/10)*I)*sqrt(3))*(-2277/10-((13/10)*I)*sqrt(3))), (2, 1) = -(1/5)*(-25372581+(8329256*I)*sqrt(3))/(-384813/10+((33701837/10)*I)*sqrt(3)), (2, 2) = -(1/5)*(-25372581-(8329256*I)*sqrt(3))/(-384813/10-((33701837/10)*I)*sqrt(3))});

AA := simplify(MatrixMatrixMultiply(Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]),Jesus7)- MatrixMatrixMultiply(Jesus7,Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]))):
```

I am using different properties and even full properties , still can not find the solution equal to exact solution, but number of equations had already been more than number of variables? where is incorrect?

```
m5 := solve([AA[1,1]=0,AA[1,2]=0,AA[2,1]=0,AA[2,2]=0, a*b = 1, c*d = 1, conjugate(a*c)-b*d = 0,a*d-b*c=sqrt(3)*I],[a,b,c,d]);

m5 := solve([AA[1,1]=0,AA[1,2]=0,AA[2,1]=0,AA[2,2]=0, a*b = 1, c*d = 1, a*d-b*c=sqrt(3)*I],[a,b,c,d]);

m5 := solve([AA[1,1]=0,AA[1,2]=0,AA[2,1]=0,AA[2,2]=0, a*b = 1, c*d = 1, conjugate(a*c)-b*d = 0],[a,b,c,d]);

m5 := solve([AA[1,1]=0,AA[1,2]=0,AA[2,1]=0,AA[2,2]=0, a*b = 1, c*d = 1],[a,b,c,d]);

Solution: Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]) should be
Jesus2 := Matrix([[1313319/2 (3439+1145 I sqrt(3))/((-2292+1313317 I sqrt(3)) (-1146+I sqrt(3))),1313319/2 (3439-1145 I sqrt(3))/((-2292-1313317 I sqrt(3)) (-1146-I sqrt(3)))],[-1/2 (-3942243+1311025 I sqrt(3))/(-2292+1313317 I sqrt(3)),-1/2 (-3942243-1311025 I sqrt(3))/(-2292-1313317 I sqrt(3))]]);
```

Comment: You should fix this so it's readable. If you do, more people will be inclined to read it and help you. Currently, it's not readable.

Comment: I add code region to be more readable, add sylvester equation and expected solution at the bottom

Comment: Simplify(determinant(jesus7)) = -sqrt(3)I  known matrix and solution has this property too, you run it maple then you will know it is exactly beautiful

Comment: Would you please state your question in mathematical language? Currently I don't understand what you are asking. The title of your question suggests that you are trying to solve a Sylvester equation $AX+XB=C$ for the unknown matrix $X$. Is that the case? If so, what are your $A,B$ and $C$? Are both $A$ and $B$ equal to your "`Jesus7`" and $C=0$? And from the first grey box in your question, it seems that $X=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ is subject to the constraints $ab=1=cd,\ \overline{ac}-bd=0$ and $ad-bc=i\sqrt{3}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can see sylvestersolve(jesus7,jesus7,matrix([[0,0],[0,0]]) as question directly,  find solution jesus2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is not solvable.

Let us restate the problem. We want to solve the Sylvester equation $AX+XA=0$, where $A$ is the $2\times2$ matrix `Jesus7` in your Maple code and the unknown matrix $X=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ is subject to the constraints that $ab=cd=1,\ \overline{ac}=bd$ and $\det(X)=ad-bc=i\sqrt{3}$.

Your $A$ is numerically close to $\pmatrix{e^{2i\pi/3}&e^{-2i\pi/3}\\ e^{-2i\pi/3}&e^{2i\pi/3}}$. I guess the difference is just rounding error, but I'll use the precise value of your `Jesus7` anyway. In general, the Sylvester equation $AX+XA=0$ has a non-trivial solution $X\ne0$ if and only if some two eigenvalues of $A$ are negatives of each other. The two eigenvalues of your $A$ are approximately $i\sqrt{3}$ and $-1$. Hence the Sylvester equation $AX+XA=0$ alone has only the trivial solution $X=0$. Yet, the additional constraints for $a,b,c,d$ imply that $X$ cannot be zero. Therefore, with these constraints, the equation is not solvable.

Comment: If ignore the constraints, only Jesus7 , how to solve? As you see that there exist a solution Jesus2, does you mean that AB + BA = 0 is not equation to relate Jesus7 and Jesus2 , if so, how do calculate Jesus2 from Jesus7?

Comment: If this is not the equation to relate them, then it give a new view, because a time series have this common characteristic , it seems a characteristic can not relate them , currently this is the only clue that can relate them, need to rethink again. These Jesus7 and Jesus2 are the eigenvectors values from a 3*3 matrix, originally think that it is near success but can not be solved.

Comment: Jesus7 is the matrix I copy from maple not typing , I have verified eigenvectors is correct , how to further check?

Comment: Sum of eigenvalues are not sqrt(3) or -1 , actually the eigenvector i use fraction to calculate , here is a photo for eigenvalues, https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L79agOm2DW3yb0s1pLJ1B2UYtcMogOmC

Comment: @PrinceMartin I don't understand these outputs. Isn't `Jesus7` a 2x2 matrix? What are those 3D vectors in the photo? Anyway, if both eigenvalues of `Jesus7` are nonzero and the matrix trace is also nonzero, then $AX+XA=0$ has only the solution $X=0$, and the equation is not solvable if the constraints on $a,b,c,d$ are also imposed.

Comment: Please see https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/224175-How-To-Display-More-Decimal-Numbers-In-Maple.    Since original 3*3 eigenvector matrix one of column and one of row are all one, and same for all time series, so I only extract the rest of it which are not one , because only need to guess 2*2 matrix. All because I start from fraction

Comment: @PrinceMartin Hmm, I'm now very confused what the true inputs are.

Comment: True inputs are just time series values with decimal numbers , I just convert to fraction then run eigenvector function